# Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package

Tags: reactjs, firebase

```
import React, {createContext} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import firebase from "firebase";
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/auth'



firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: "AIzaSyBl0uavX6asIMdOhkpGldLRoJ7smEDomaE",
        authDomain: "chat-a12dd.firebaseapp.com",
        projectId: "chat-a12dd",
        storageBucket: "chat-a12dd.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "331463305578",
        appId: "1:331463305578:web:e34a2cde64938749115d13"
    }
);

export const Context = createContext(null)

const auth = firebase.auth()
const firestore = firebase.firestore()

ReactDOM.render(
    <Context.Provider value={{
        firebase,
        auth,
        firestore
    }}>
            <App />
    </Context.Provider>,

  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

> ERROR in ./src/index.js 7:0-32 Module not found: Error: Package path .
> is not exported from package
> C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\real-time-chat\node_modules\firebase
> (see exports field in
> C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\real-time-chat\node_modules\firebase\package.json)

Я так понимаю, что проблема с экспортом?

Answer (score 0):

Изменил версию Firebase в Package.json на "firebase": "^8.0.0"
И импорт на: import firebase from 'firebase/app'